# WebView on custom dialog box adds extra margin in right of dialog box - Android

Tags: android, android-webview, animated-gif

I am trying to add `gif` on the custom dialog box in android. I have set `height` and `width` of the view as *wrap_content*. Still, it adds more margin and increases the width of the dialog box.

If I use ImageView instead of WebView then it works fine. Following is my code with WebView, on button click it shows dialog box:

```
Button button =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog builder = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setContentView(R.layout.web_view_dialog);
            WebView webView = builder.findViewById(R.id.gif_view);
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test_gif.gif");
        builder.show();
        }
    });
```

web_view_dialog.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/gif_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</WebView>
```

Please refer the following gif:

[image: extra_spacing_in_dialogbox_webview]

**It works when we use ImageView instead of WebView, but in case of WebView how to remove this extra margin from dialog box?**

Answer (score 0):

```
##Edited  Place this it works well i think
<WebView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gif_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: changing *parent* layout to wrap_content and having webView inside gives warning as `it may lead to subtle bugs and recommend to use match_parent`.
Still, I checked by changing it to wrap_content, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please Paste the above code working.

And Dependency..
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}

repositories {
    google()
}

Comment: I have tried the above code. It's not working. Getting the same result.

Comment: with constraints you are getting same..please paste the same code without any changes.. it works

Comment: Sure @satyan_android, Please have a look.

Comment: WebView webView = (WebView)builder.findViewById(R.id.gif_view);
any way.. I dont think so.. Please do this one.. and Please check in other devices also Once we will get Clarity

Comment: please watch your GIF once in Chrome or Explorer .. That the image or gif was having any spaces or not..

Comment: There no extra margin for Gif. If I use ImageView instead of WebView and pass the link in `src` then that image works fine. It doesn't appear with extra margin.

Comment: Edited XML check once

Comment: not working, this has increased the width. Is this working at your end?

Comment: the above xml with one tag is also not working... can u check on other devices

Comment: it's Not working, checked on other devices also. I guess WebView adds some margin.